# Error with Amazon S3 for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a great Wordpress to store files on Amazon S3 called "Amazon S3 for WordPress" it seems to have a bug with version 3.0+ of Wordpress.

The error I am getting is:

> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1
>   to be string, array given in
>   /home/dir/public_html/www.site.com/wp-admin/includes/media.php
>   on line 310

Here is the code in media.php around line 310:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'global' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-admin' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'colors' );
// Check callback name for 'media'
if ( ( is_array( $content_func ) && ! empty( $content_func[1] ) && 0 === strpos( (string) $content_func[1], 'media' ) ) || 0 === strpos( $content_func, 'media' ) )
    wp_enqueue_style( 'media' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'ie' );
```

I would love some clue as to what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: What does the code block around the mentioned line look like?

Comment: <?php
wp_enqueue_style( 'global' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-admin' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'colors' );
// Check callback name for 'media'
if ( ( is_array( $content_func ) && ! empty( $content_func[1] ) && 0 === strpos( (string) $content_func[1], 'media' ) ) || 0 === strpos( $content_func, 'media' ) )

Line 310 is the if statement.
 wp_enqueue_style( 'media' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'ie' );
?>
</pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think you've found a bug in WordPress. The line of code that's throwing the error is this:

```
if ( ( is_array( $content_func ) && ! empty( $content_func[1] ) && 0 === strpos( (string) $content_func[1], 'media' ) ) || 0 === strpos( $content_func, 'media' ) )
```

If you look at that, the second scenario assumes `$content_func` is a string and passes it through `strpos`

Maybe something like

```
if ( ( is_array( $content_func ) && ! empty( $content_func[1] ) && 0 === strpos( (string) $content_func[1], 'media' ) ) || ( is_string( $content_func ) && 0 === strpos( (string)$content_func, 'media' ) ) )
```

Would work better.